Can non-residents exchange a foreign licence for a New Zealand driving licence?
I am visiting New Zealand for an extended period of time as a tourist, and stumbled upon the question of how easy is it to convert a foreign licence (e.g. US/UK/Germany) to an NZ licence. I had a look at a couple of sources:

The NZ AA website's guide: https://www.aa.co.nz/drivers/driver-licences/overseas-licence-conversions/
The overseas driving licence exchange application form: https://www.nzta.govt.nz/assets/resources/application-conversion-overseas-licence-dl5/docs/dl5.pdf

It seems to me from reading through those that all that's needed is to turn up with a valid test-exempt foreign licence, foreign passport, some photocopies and a completed application form. Is there really no residency requirement such that a tourist could turn up and exchange their foreign licence, aside from needing an address for the application?

I feel this is more expats, not travel, but would like to see what others think.

@Willeke I'm inclined to agree; while the question concerns "tourists" it also concerns "visit for an extended period of time" and we have historically given more weight to the duration of the visit than its purpose when distinguishing the two sites.

Note that in some countries, 'exchange' means exactly that. You'll have to turn over your foreign driver's license. Because you'll still have residence (I assume) in your citizenship country, maybe it won't be much trouble to replace your 'lost' one or just get a new one.


Is there really no residency requirement such that a tourist could turn up and exchange their foreign licence, aside from needing an address for the application?

There is no residency requirement. Residency (i.e. immigration status) and fitness/qualification to drive are separate concerns, and New Zealand does not conflate them. NZ driver's licence proves your identity, qualification to drive and, if you want so, your NZ address. It does not reflect or imply anything about your immigration status.
There are more requirements though than an NZ address. Your existing licence must be:

From an exempt country
Current or expired within the last 12 months
Not suspended, disqualified or revoked
Issued more than 2 years ago (otherwise you'll need to pass a practical driving test)

You'll also need to pass eyesight check.

While it is true that residence and fitness to drive are separate concerns, it is also true that issuing driver's licenses is typically held to be a function of the driver's place of residence.  Also, residence is a separate concern from immigration status for most purposes.

@phoog In NZ, "residence" (or "residency") is used to refer to an immigration status. It is equivalent of LPR in the US and ILR in the UK, and I am using this term as such. It is also what the OP seems to mean.

As a counterexample disproving that assertion, I note the Retirement Villages Act 2003, which tells residents of retirement villages that they have "the right to information relating to any matters affecting, or likely to affect, the terms or conditions of [their] residency."  This clearly has nothing to do with immigration status.

@phoog I am not saying that the term is not used in that, more mundane meaning too. The use of it as an immigration status does not preclude using it to mean something else.

@phoog Maybe NZ is not like most other countries then? It's also a fact that in the Cook Islands, an NZ dependency, any tourist can march into the cop shop at Rarotonga and leave 10 minutes later with a shiny new Cook Islands driving license.

@Greendrake but "residency i.e. immigration status" implies that it is the immigration status aspect that is important for driver licensing, and that is not the case in many jurisdictions.

@phoog How "many jurisdictions" are relevant to this question? It's specifically about NZ if you didn't notice.

I find this lack of a residency requirement fascinating, thank you for confirming it. I previously tried to exchange a US licence for a German licence (I am a German citizen) and I was informed I had to have an Anmeldung (registration of my place of residence with the local authorities, and hence likely a tax liability) and had to be living there for at least 6 months. The UK similarly requires at least 6 months of residence before one can apply for a licence.
